# Не открывается нужный activity с notification(android)

Tags: java, android, уведомления

У меня есть 2 Activity(`Activity1`, `Activity2`). `Activity1` - это home экран приложения, на `Activity2` я могу попасть только с `Activity1`(там есть кнопка), а еще я могу попасть на `Activity2` с `notification`. У меня такая ситуация, если приложение открыто и мне приходит пуш, при нажатии на него я перехожу на `Activity2`. Но если приложение закрыто, я нажимаю на пуш то я перехожу на `Activity1`, почему? Я потратил уже несколько дней, использовал много способов, но у меня ничего не работает. Если знаете, подскажите пожалуйста. Использую GCM.

**класс соушает пуш**

```
public class GcmMessageHandler extends GcmListenerService {

    static int count = 0;

     @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
String name = notification.getString("title");
String message = notification.getString("body");

 Resources res = ctx.getResources();
             PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
             PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
             wl.acquire(15000);

             NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
             mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);

             mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification); 
             mBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.icon));

             mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000});
             mBuilder.setTicker(name + ":" + message);
             mBuilder.setContentText(message);
             mBuilder.setContentTitle(name);
             mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
             mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
             mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));


            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


             PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                     PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            ctx,
                            count,
                             i,
                             PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            NotificationManager myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                     ctx.getSystemService(ctx.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

             myNotificationManager.notify(count, mBuilder.build());
}

}
```

пробовал и не помогло:

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE
PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
в место PendingIntent ставил 0
```

Мой **манифест**(части связанные с пуш) и Activity2:

```
    <!-- GCM -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

         <permission android:name="myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
        <uses-permission android:name="myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
        <!-- GCM END -->

<!-- Activity 2 -->
  <activity
            android:name=".Activity2"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
<!-- Activity 2 end-->


    <!-- GCM -->
             <receiver
                android:name="push.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <category android:name="myapp" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <service android:name="push.GcmMessageHandler" />

            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 

            <!-- GCM -->
```

**Activity2**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitytwo);
    }

}
```

**UPD**

если я даже укажу вот так(код ниже), когда приложение закрыто мой Activity2 не откроется. Откроется Activity1

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                ctx,
                                count,
                                new Intent(ctx, Activity2.class),
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: А вот такой флаг пробовали? FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, пробовал просто `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` и `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` не работает

Comment: Ну... Добавьте, что ли, описание второй активити из манифеста.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил в манифес описание активити2 и код активити2

Comment: А если вот это из манифеста убрать? `android:launchMode="singleTop"`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб попробовал, не работает

Comment: Ну... Работать должно... Я вижу для вас только один путь - создать с нуля чистый проект и написать в нём вызов простого уведомления с простым переходом в простое активити. После этого добавлять то, что у вас есть сейчас и следить в какой момент перестанет работать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб была выявлена причина открывание не того активити. Дело в том что сервер генерирует json вида https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support т.е андроид когда приложение закрыто, само создает пуш стандартными средствами. И что б открывать нужный активити, нужно передать с сервера `click_action` а в манифесте назначить `click_action` на класс. Только вот теперь не понятно как передавать какие то параметры `putExtra`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, надо добавить

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
```

в описание активити в манифесте, кою вы хотите запускать извне приложения.

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял то нужно сделать вот так? `<activity
            android:name=".Activity2"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   </intent-filter>
        </activity>` если да, то не работает(